# In Flutter Is it possible to show the image and the video in the same widget, Are there any common widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show the image and the video in the common widget, Are there any common widget in the flutter to show image and the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any such widgets in-built flutter.

You can create a custom widget.**PhotoVideoViewWidget** as shown in the code.

```
class PhotoVideoViewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String type;
  final String url;

  const PhotoVideoViewWidget({Key key, this.type, this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return type == "video"
        ? VideoViewWidget(
            videoUrl: url,
          )
        : PhotoViewWidget(
            imageUrl: url,
          );
  }
}

class PhotoViewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageUrl;

  const PhotoViewWidget({Key key, this.imageUrl}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PhotoViewer(imageUrl);
  }
}

class VideoViewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String videoUrl;

  const VideoViewWidget({Key key, this.videoUrl}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return VideoViewer(videoUrl);
  }
}
```